# Matlab Returns "FAIL" When Trying to Invert Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to invert a matrix with some symbolic variables, but Matlab just returns 'FAIL'.  I'm using inv(K).  This is K that Matlab outputs after some computation:

```
K = 

[  11/80,   7/80, -11/80,  -7/80, 0, 0]
[   7/80,  11/80,  -7/80, -11/80, 0, 0]
[ -11/80,  -7/80,  11/80,   7/80, 0, 0]
[  -7/80, -11/80,   7/80,  11/80, 0, 0]
[      0,      0,      0,      0, 0, 0]
[      0,      0,      0,      0, 0, 0]

invK = inv(K);

FAIL
```

Note that my matrix in my script looks like this (for example):

```
K = [1,2,3;
     3,2,1;
     1,1,1];
```

Comment: you use this format for defining a matrix or just did for representation purposes? I think you matrix definitions is not formal for Matlab, or am I wrong?

Comment: This is what Matlab outputs.  See edit for what the matrix in my script looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That matrix is 6x6 but its rank is not more than three, therefore it is not invertible.  Only full rank matrices can be inverted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pinv` . It gives you the pseudo inverse. That might give you something. In case you are stuck with this and only this matrix. Else if you are learning about matrix inverses then you should go with the answer already here on the thread.